# How to make VoiceOver read out a different text than what's in the UITextView?

Tags: swift, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a UITextView containing a text that is meant for sighted users. I want to add a different non-sighted user-friendly text that will be read-out when VoiceOver is on. I tried adding it as an accessibilityLabel, but VoiceOver read both text. How can I make it read out just the accessible text when VoiceOver is on?

Comment: Try setting the accessibility value instead of (or as well as) the accessibility label

Answer (score 1):

it read out just the accessible text when VoiceOver is on below code useful

```
UITextView.AccessibilityValue="Your Text";
```

In that You pass text which

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to vocalize a text that's different from the displayed one using a UITextView with VoiceOver... anyway, I haven't found any solution for that.

VoiceOver is not only used by blind people but also by sight-impaired people which means that it's important to maintain a link between what's displayed and what's vocalized.

Using a UITextView means that **its text will be vocalized besides the possible accessibility label** you add.

If you want to **make it read out just the accessible text when VoiceOver is on** :

- Listen to the [UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-events) event.
- Update the text of your UITextView accordingly : `myTextView.text = "text to be adapted to the context."`

Following these steps will allow you to reach your goal.